# Asymptotic efficiency of IQR

Tags: covariance, order-statistics, efficiency, range, interquartile

I was wondering about the asymptotic efficiency of the Interquartile Range (IQR) in the Gaussian case. I have calculated it empirically using a Monte Carlo estimator, and it appears to be equal to that of the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) (36.75%).

However, I have not found any literature on this topic. Specifically, I have not found a formula for the covariance between two order statistics to calculate its variance. Indeed, for a vector $X$ of size $N=4n+1$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have : $$\widehat{IQR}(X)=Q(X,.75)-Q(X,.25)=X_{(3n+1)}-X_{(n+1)}$$.

So $\text{Var}(\widehat{IQR}(X)) = \text{Var}(X_{(3n+1)}+\text{Var}(X_{(n+1)})-2\text{Cov}(X_{(3n+1)},X_{(n+1)})$.

I've found an approximation of the variance of order statistic [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394960/variance-of-normal-order-statistics) but nothing on the covariance.

If you have any references on efficiency of IQR or on covariance of order statistics of a Gaussian distribution feel free to help me!

Comment: Asymptotically, the median converges to the mean, and for a symmetric distribution the median of the deviations from the median will be obtained at the 0.25 and 0.75-quantile (which will asymptotically have an equal deviation from the median). That's why the asymptotic efficiency of MAD and IQR are the same.

Comment: Thank you Christian !!

Answer (score 10):

**Asymptotic distribution of the interquartile range**

The asymptotic distribution of the interquartile range for the normal distribution is shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111159/21054). Let $f$ be the density, $F$ the CDF and the population quantile function be $F^{-1}(p)$ of a random variable. Further, let $F^{-1}(p) = \xi_{p}$. Then, the following holds asymptotically:
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\mathrm{IQR} - \left(\xi_{\frac{3}{4}}-\xi_{\frac{1}{4}}\right)\right)\xrightarrow{d} \mathrm{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{16}\left[\frac{3}{f^{2}(\xi_{\frac{3}{4}})}+\frac{3}{f^{2}(\xi_{\frac{1}{4}})}-\frac{2}{f(\xi_{\frac{1}{4}})f(\xi_{\frac{3}{4}})}\right]\right)
$$

For iid observations of a normal distribution $\mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma^{2})$, this result simplifies to:
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\mathrm{IQR} - 1.349\sigma\right)\xrightarrow{d} \mathrm{N}\left(0, 2.476\sigma^{2}\right)
$$
So asymptotically, the standard deviation is $1.573\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}}$.

In summary, the IQR of a normal distribution $\mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ is asymptotically normally distributed with mean $F^{-1}_{\mu, \sigma^2}(3/4)-F^{-1}_{\mu, \sigma^2}(1/4)$ (i.e. the population IQR) and variance $2.47569\sigma^2/n$.

Let's check that with a small simulation:

```R
# Parameters
mu <- 100
sigma <- 15
n <- 5000

# Asymptotic variance of IQR
varfac <- (1/2)*exp(2*(qnorm(1/2/2, lower.tail = FALSE)/sqrt(2))^2)*pi
# Population IQR
true_iqr <- qnorm(3/4, mu, sigma) - qnorm(1/4, mu, sigma)

# Simulation
set.seed(142857)
res <- replicate(1e5, {
  IQR(rnorm(n, mu, sigma))
})

# Mean and variance of simulated IQRs
mean(res)
[1] 20.2288
var(res)
[1] 0.1117288
varfac*sigma^2/n
[1] 0.111406
```

For $n=5000$, the agreement is excellent.

**Relative efficiency**

For the standard deviation, we have according to the delta method
$$
\sqrt{n}(s_n-\sigma)\xrightarrow{d} \operatorname{N}\left(0, \frac{\mu_4-\sigma^4}{4\sigma^2}\right)
$$
where $\mu_4$ is the 4th central moment. For a normal distribution, this simplifies to $\operatorname{N}\left(0, 1/2\sigma^2\right)$. A consistent estimate of $\sigma$ of a normal distribution is $\operatorname{IQR}/1.349$ which has an asymptotic variance of $2.476/1.349^2=1.361$. Hence, the asymptotic efficiency of the interquartile range relative to the standard deviation is the ratio of their asymptotic variances, namely $(1/2)/1.361=0.367$.

Comment: Nice work.  My conclusion is that like the median and quartiles, the IQR is not precise enough for small to moderate $n$.  Check out Gini's mean difference.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks Frank. I'm aware of Gini's mean difference. Its ARE is 97.79% at the normal compared to the standard deviation and much more efficient in heavy tailed distributions. One main advantage is that as a U-statistic, GMD is unbiased in finite samples for all distribution with finite first moments (Gerstenberger & Vogel 2015). I really should be reported more often.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really nice work !!